# is it OK to use multiple blades of a feeler gauge to measure a larger gap

Tags: tools, measurement

This feels like a bit of a silly question because I don't see any reason why it won't work fine - but I wanted to get some experienced/pro feedback. I need to measure a gap of .035 inches, my feeler gauge ranges up to .025 .  My plan is to measure the gap by extending both the 0.025 and 0.010 blades and pressing them together with my fingers, then measuring as usual.

Can I expect this to yield an accurate measurement? and is this a "correct" or "normal" way to use a feeler gauge?

Comment: I've seen people do it, and I think it should be accurate and perfectly fine, but I'm no machinist, so maybe one of them should answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works as long as they are clean.

What is the tolerance on the gap you are working with? Compare that to the error of putting two feeler gauges together - check with a micrometer or vernier preferably a good one.

Comment: In this case it's for spark plugs so it'll definitely be fine, but I wanted to keep the question general. Great point about the condition/cleanliness of the tool being relevant, if it was gunked up I'd be doubling the resulting error,  and of course the specific application matters a lot, thanks.